# Simplify where clause with repeated associated type restrictions

Tags: generics, rust, where-clause

I wrote the following function to sum over an iterator:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn sum_iter<I>(s: I, init: &I::Item) -> I::Item
where
    I: Iterator + Clone,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: Add<I::Item, Output = I::Item> + Copy,
{
    s.clone().fold(*init, |acc, item| acc + item)
}
```

This compiles fine with Rust 1.0.0, but it would be nice if one could avoid repeating `I::Item` four times and instead refer to a type `T` and say somewhere that `Iterator::Item = T` only once. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can add `T` as a type parameter for your function, and require `I` to implement `Iterator<Item = T>`, like this:

```
fn sum_iter<I, T>(s: I, init: &T) -> T
where
    I: Iterator<Item = T> + Clone,
    T: Add<T, Output = T> + Copy,
{
    s.clone().fold(*init, |acc, item| acc + item)
}
```